# Undefined is not a valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

Problem it is showing
[image: Problem it is showing]

The code of store.js
[image: The code of store.js]

It show that undefined is not a valid JSON . But I cannot figure Out what is the problem .

I want a proper solution for this error with the explanation so that in near future  I can solve it by my own

Comment: Post your code of `store.js` instead of an image

Comment: With the limited info, here's my guessing: 1. your `cartItem` property has a value of `undefined` & 2. you can't `JSON.parse` something that's not a JSON.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `JSON.stringify`; but otherwise I see you are expecting a value of empty array if there's no localStorage of property `cartItems`, since `.getItem()` returns a value from a property in the localStorage, instead of JSON.parse maybe you meant to wrap it in an array like `[localStorage.getItem("cartItems")]`